# Handling Daylight Savings Using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a website in Wordpress which needs to handle Daylight Savings Time effectively. 
I have made two PHP functions one to store Local user time as UTC on server, db and another to convert server UTC time to Local User time for display.

They are as follows:-

```
//display saved UTC dates to Local user time

function ServerTimeToLocal($serverTime){
    $user_id=get_current_user_id();
    $user_timezone = get_user_meta($user_id, "user_timezone", true);

    date_default_timezone_set(SERVER_TZ);   
    $utc_start_stamp = strtotime($serverTime);

    date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone );

    $whichday_local =  date("D", $utc_start_stamp);
    $start_time_local =  date("h:i A", $utc_start_stamp);

    return array("day"=>$whichday_local, "time"=>$start_time_local);
}

//store local user time as UTC on server
function LocalTimeToServer($localTime){
    $user_id=get_current_user_id();
    $user_timezone = get_user_meta($user_id, "user_timezone", true);

            //store timings by local time
    date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone );

    $start_timestamp = strtotime($localTime);
            //convert to server timezone
    date_default_timezone_set(SERVER_TZ);

            //echo $whichday." ".$start_time." ";

    $whichday_server = date("D", $start_timestamp);
    $start_time_server =  date("h:i A", $start_timestamp);
    return array("day"=>$whichday_server, "time"=>$start_time_server);  
}
```

Although I know that date('I') is used to determine whether Daylight savings time(DST) is in effect, how do I factor in DST into my functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I usually handle DST like so...

```
if( date('I') != 1 )
{
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + 3600 ));
}

return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will check if daylight savings time is in effect, if it is then it will return the date, and add on the hour. If not, it will just return the date.

I have this wrapped in a function getDate(). Comes in really handy

Comment: there's quite a few timezones that AREN'T at 1hour increments, e.g. NST - newfoundland has a 30 minute offset.

Comment: Just need to modify the amount being added to time().

I use this because I store the times in GMT. If you want to record NST, just add 1800 to the time()

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php this link says "I (capital i)  Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time 1 if Daylight Saving Time, 0 otherwise." So should it be <?php if( date('I') == 1 )
{
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + 3600 ));
}

return date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>

Comment: Nope, this is the function I use in every app I develop, it gives the correct GMT time every time

Answer (score 0):

Since you noted WordPress, you should be using WordPress' native functions to do this instead of writing your own.

For example, instead of your `ServerTimeToLocal()` use [`get_gmt_from_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_gmt_from_date).

Comment: get_gmt_from_date(). will help me convert local time to utc if I am not  mistaken , is there anything in Wordpress that will help me do the reverse, namely, convert UTC to local time taking Daylight Savings Time into consideration?